# Adding optional insurance service to existing shipping service

Tags: commerce

This is my first question here, sorry if I miss something and for my bad english.
I have a D7 drupal commerce site, and custom wants to add an optional insurance for shipping. There is only 1 shipping service calculated with shipping weight tariff module. At checkout users should be ablen to choice wether buying insurance for shipping or not. If yes I should add 10% of order total with at least 10€ amount.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably add this using a combination of Rules (module) plus an additional custom field for Shipping line items.

Comment: Ok,I've created a custom fiels for Shipping line item type (my installation is in italian, I hope that's the correct english label); the field is boolean: the aim is let the user choose if buy the service or not. But where I can see in checkout progress the boolean field?thanks

Comment: There's a couple ways. One way is to use Checkout Panes, but that may not be necessary if you added a field as a Shipping line item, it should appear on it's own during the checkout process.

Comment: Here are some Drupal Commerce videos around customized shipping that may help.

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/videos/tutorials/free-shipping-based-order-value-or-user-role ...and... 

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/videos/tutorials/shipping-discount-item-cart-using-calculation-rules ...and...

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/videos/demo/introduction-commerce-shipping

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying in this way:
- I've created a new fee with Commerce Fees
- Created two shipping service, say "Service 1" and "Service 2", with the same calculation rule (I use Weight Shipping tariff)
- Created a rule: when shipping service is "Service 2", apply the fee.

The fee is based on total amount, while the shipping tariff is based on totale weight.

The problem is my insurance service figure as shippping service, not as an optional service in a new checkout step. It would be choosen not among shipping services, but in another step.

So, I'm trying this solution:

- created a new checkout page with Commerce Checkout Pages
- created a new checkout pane with Commerce extra panes, named "Insurance"

Now I would create something like a checkbox in "Insurance" pane to let the user choose to purchase the service or not; than get the value of input field, and write a rule like this: "if input field is checked, apply the fee to total order amount", using appropriate rules event, provided by Commerce Fees module.

Ho could I make that form or input filed in my custom pane and than get the value for rules?

Thank you very much.